# How much each color plays in contributing in the determination of the overall brightness in hex notation

Tags: color, color-theory, hex

What color does it has the most light component between #010101 or just #000001??

**edit**

For brightness I mean the nearness to the white (nearest to FF in hex).

At the time of the question I wanted to know how much each color plays in contributing in the determination of the overall brightness. Moreover, does the lighter component determinate the most overall brightness or the bright of the less bright colors contribute to augment the overall brightness summing theirselves to the already brighter color?

For example, which color between #010101 and #000001 is the most bright?

As of the answer, every color plays the same role and they are also summed up together determining a brighter color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB is the sum of three channels of brightness (red, green, blue), so to parse out your hex values as
**rgb( 1, 1, 1 )**
vs.
**rgb( 0, 0, 1 )**

the first color would have a greater amount of total brightness.

Comment: In common RGB-to-brightness algorithms, green is (substantially) brighter than red, which in turn is brighter than blue. An approximation is `L = 0.30*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B` (PAL/SECAM); there are others, based on sRGB/YUV, but the idea is the same.

Comment: That is a more substantial answer, but since his original question was unclear, I was not fully invested in my response. Thanks, Rad.

Comment: I meant to get the original answer. It was just a silly question I had, for me it's now clear how it works.